# Concerns with SoapUI Pro when Updating Web Services

Tags: wsdl, soapui, regression

This may unfortunately be a very open-ended question, but a coworker of mine has shared concerns about using SoapUI Pro as our automated regression testing tool primarily on the basis that seemingly trivial WSDL changes can cause headaches for the QA crew. My coworker's particularly concerned that if we update the WSDL, even with a name change, we'll need to touch and update each existing test where that field is used.

As I understand it SoapUI Pro offers a refactoring tool to handle this for you.

What are your experiences with SoapUI Pro and updating your web services? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar concerns and this can be a slight issue; however.

1. Even when it does happen the benefits to productivity out weight downside.
2. You can use Groovy Scripts to refactor the project itself.
3. Apply good programming practices to isolate commonality.
4. layer the project, create extremely simple API primitives.
5. create separate test suites for scenarios that use those primities rather than making the calls themselves
6. Use Groovy and the TestRunner, link in external Java utilities and helper code
7. DO NOT CLONE, call instead.
8. Use external tools, I also use XmlPad & Notepad++ refactor my SOAPUI project.

Answer (score 0):

You can update wsdl definition in you project and also recreate updated request and take backup of old requests.

Here is the code to do that.

```
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateRequests
import static com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.iface.UpdateInterfaceAction.recreateTestRequests

project = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project; //get the project reference
def ifaceList = project.getInterfaceList(); //get all the interfaces present in the project in a list

//start a loop for number of interfaces
for(int i = 0; i < project.getInterfaceCount() ; i++)
{

def iface = project.getInterfaceAt(i);
def url = iface.definition;
iface.updateDefinition( url, true); //updateDefinition(String url , Boolean createRequests)

//The above part updates the definition
//The part below recreates the requests based on updated wsdl definition

//syntax - 
//recreateRequests( WsdlInterface iface, boolean buildOptional, boolean createBackups, boolean keepExisting, boolean keepHeaders )

recreateRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
recreateTestRequests(iface,true,true,true,true);
}
//End of Script//
```